# Merge row values into a CSV (a.k.a GROUP_CONCAT for SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like:

```
EntityID   AttributeID  OptionText
5016       20           Paintings
5044       18           Female
5060       48           M
5060       48           F
5060       49           Apple
5060       49           Banana
5060       49           Cat
```

I want to create a view that will show:

```
5016    20   Paintings
5044    18   Female
5060    48   M,F
5060    49   Apple, Banana, Cat
```

Means The attributes values on every entity should be displayed separated by a comma.

The number of options can be varied.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For each pair of `EntityID, AttributeID` use the XML path trick to generate the CSV

```
 SELECT
    M.EntityID, M.AttributeID,
    SUBSTRING(CAST(foo.bar AS varchar(8000)), 2, 7999) AS Options
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT EntityID, AttributeID
    FROM MyTable
    ) M
    CROSS APPLY
    (
    SELECT
        ',' + OptionText
    FROM
        MyTable M2
    WHERE
        M.EntityID = M2.EntityID AND M.AttributeID= M2.AttributeID
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) foo(bar)
```

Comment: Would there be any noticeable performance difference between `SUBSTRING` and `CAST` versus `STUFF(( ... ), 1, 2, '')`?

Comment: @Seph: marginal, don't know which way. The bulk of resources and time will be the JOINs and the XML processing. Not removing the first comma.

Comment: Thanks for solving the query but i am still facing performance issues. The table is going to have more than 1 million records. In this case even to fetch just few records the time taken is more than 2 seconds.

Comment: @Kamal Deep Singh: you have an index problem then. Ask a new question with table schema and indexes.

Comment: @gbn Actually the issue is the table i have shown you is actually a view. I have not apply indexing of its own. The index will be default if provided by the sql server. I am actually applying a model similar to EAV model in this case i need such a condition.

Comment: @Kamal Deep Singh: Don't ask a 2nd question in comments

Comment: Found this useful. Very nice!

Answer (score 4):

Try the code below (I've included all test SQL so you don't have to practice on live data). You can view a working example here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/115141/

```
--Set up test table
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (EntityID INT, AttributeID INT, OptionText VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #Table1
SELECT  5030, 48, 'M'

INSERT INTO #Table1
SELECT  5030, 48, 'F'

--Begin actual working SQL          
SELECT      T1.EntityID,
            T1.AttributeID,
            STUFF(( SELECT    ', ' + T2.OptionText
                    FROM      #Table1 T2
                    WHERE     T2.AttributeID = T1.AttributeID
                    AND       T2.EntityID = T1.EntityID
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                  ), 1, 2, '') [Attributes]
FROM        #Table1 T1
GROUP BY    T1.EntityID, T1.AttributeID

DROP TABLE #Table1
```

Comment: The query is very helpful  but i am still facing performance issues. The table is going to have more than 1 million records. In this case even to fetch just few records the time taken is more than 2 seconds. Is there is any alternative for this.

Answer (score 2):

I have done some tests with 3 different methods:

http://blog.feronovak.com/2011/10/multiple-values-in-one-column-aka.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Since this is a frequent task for us, we ended up making it a function similar to your Method #1.  The xml path trick works too, but the function makes the SQL easier to read.