# Merge record values into a record that contains multiple values with comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a many-to-many table schema like this,

```
|------------|          |--------------|            |-----------|
| Products   |-|-------<|ProductEngine |>---------|-|  Engines  |
|            |          |              |            |           |
|------------|          |--------------|            |-----------|
```

After inner join query, I've got a result set below:

```
SELECT product_id, engine_id 
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN ProductEngine 
  ON Products.product_id=ProductEngine.product_id

+---------------+--------------+
| product_id    | engine_id    |
+---------------+--------------+
| P001          | E001         |
| P001          | E002         |
| P002          | E003         |
| P002          | E004         |
| P002          | E005         |
+---------------+--------------+
```

How do I write SQL query if I want to get a result like this?

```
+---------------+----------------+
| product_id    | engine_id      |
+---------------+----------------+
| P001          | E001,E002      |
| P002          | E003,E004,E005 |
+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate values based on ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603319/concatenate-values-based-on-id)

Comment: and of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7755815/27535 and 100s of others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are [several techniques to converting row values into a string](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/#_Toc205129486), I like this one:

```
SELECT p1.product_id,
       substring(
          ( SELECT ',' + engine_id
              FROM ProductEngine p2
              WHERE p2.product_id = p1.product_id
              FOR XML PATH('') ), 2, 4000)
       AS engine_id
      FROM Products p1;
```

**Edited**

Now is working as you need. [I have write an example to you](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/121397/).

Comment: There is an error "Column 'Products.product_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: When I removed the GROUP BY clause, it works but there's a ',' left in the engine_id column.(E001,E002,)(E003,E004,E005,)