# How do I get a comma delimited result from result set without using parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I get a commma delimited result from the following example with no parameters and from a single query:

```
select FirstName + ' ' LastName from table_of_Names where NameType='game show host'

Bob Barker, Willie Aammes, Steve Allen, Clive Anderson
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge row values into a CSV (a.k.a GROUP_CONCAT for SQL Server)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755815/merge-row-values-into-a-csv-a-k-a-group-concat-for-sql-server)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/q/6603319/27535

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With parameters (better performance):

```
DECLARE @list VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @list = COALESCE(@list + ', ' , '') + FirstName + ' ' + LastName 
FROM table_of_Names where NameType='game show host'

SELECT @list
```

Without parameters (not as performant):

```
select stuff((select ','+ FirstName + ' ' + LastName
              FROM table_of_Names where NameType='game show host'
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as NameList
```

Comment: Thanks that looks good, but I'm really trying to do this in a single query with no declare variables or parameters.

Comment: @RetroCoder: in which case, look at the duplicates. This is a very common question... unless you want us to write the code for you...

Comment: lol, just wrote it for you... revised my answer based on your comment RetroCoder.

Comment: When you do this look at the actual execution plan.  The first option with parameters is SO much faster than the STUFF example I included.

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way I know of is to write a stored procedure that iterates through the result set and appends the comma and space, for all rows except the last.

Comment: why would you do that? Simple research shows you far better methods and it's asked several times a day

Comment: There are lots of different ways to do this, and looping is rarely a good idea in SQL.