# Complex join with coalesce

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, coalesce

I have a table that I am stuffing demographic info into and then using dynamic sql to build a table from that. The demographic info comes from surveys and some of the surveys have checkboxes. With checkboxes people can select multiple values.

So I need to enter all the choices as a comma seperated list.

```
CREATE TABLE Demographics 
  (
    QID NVARCHAR(15)
    ,userid NVARCHAR(50)
    ,question NVARCHAR(800)
    ,choice NVARCHAR(1000)
  )
...
...
--Demographics(QID,userid,question,choice)
--'Insert checkbox (type 5)
INSERT INTO Demographics
SELECT CAST(q.QID AS NVARCHAR(15))
    ,ri.userid
    ,q.QuestionText
    ,ac.Choice
FROM ResponseInfo ri --response details
JOIN Responses r ON ri.ResponseID = r.ResponseID --actual response
JOIN Questions q ON r.QID = q.QID --question info
JOIN AnswerChoices ac ON r.QID = ac.QID --answer choice text
WHERE (q.QuestionTypeID = 5 AND q.QID = ac.QID
AND r.IsOther = 0 
AND q.QID = 16
)
AND ri.userid IN (SELECT userid FROM @Users) AND r.Response = ac.Sequence
ORDER BY ri.userid
...
dynamic sql stuff
...
EXEC sp_exesql @sql
```

My results look like this:

```
users | question_15 | choice_15 | question_16     | choice_16 |
bill  | age?        | 37        | favorite color? | red       |
bill  | age?        | 37        | favorite color? | green     |
```

But it needs to be:

```
users | question_15 | choice_15 | question_16     | choice_16 |
bill  | age?        | 37        | favorite color? | red,green |
```

I tried doing

```
,COALESCE(ac.Choice + ',','') + ac.Choice
```

It gave me

```
bill  | age?        | 37        | favorite color? | red,red   |
```

Can anyone help me sort this out?

Comment: how many possible values can be for `choice_16`?

Comment: In this case 8 I think. It is one of those "are you hispanic or not?" Oh well either way "click every ethnicity that applies to you". "Decline to answer" is always a choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755815/merge-row-values-into-a-csv-a-k-a-group-concat-for-sql-server).

Very helpful. My code could probably use some cleaning up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using SQL Server. If you're using a recentish version of SQL Server (e.g., SQL Server 2005 or later), you'd likely be better off storing your data as XML.

That lets you use XPATH/XQUERY in SQL to manipulate the XML data to get what you want. I think you'll find that easier to do.

- http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-xml-cribsheet/
- http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/beginning-sql-server-2005-xml-programming/