# How to concatenate data output separated values?

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, csv, concatenation

I'm creating a view to serve as a matrix report that displays row data from various tables as columns. I think it can achieve this through concatenation but I’m a little stuck. My query works excellent however I’m using an inversed datatable (pivot table) which is displayed in a gridview and what I’m getting at present is all my multiple values are adding together in each cell!

```
Set Name    James   Smith   Jones
Training 1      9       5       7
Training 2      5       7       8
Training 3     12      10       9
```

This is what I'd like to output!

```
Set Name    James    Smith     Jones
Training 1  3,1,2,3  2,3       5,2
Training 2  4,1      1,1,5     2,2,2,2 
Training 3  1,4,4,3  2,2,2,4   1,3,2,3
```

I have a many-to-many relationship between users and training since one user can have many instances of training with multiple outcomes over certain periods of time.

The `userProfilesTbl`  This table stores additional user information from the ASP.NET membership, roles and profiles tables.

```
•   PK UserId (int) 
•   StaffNo (varchar) 
•   forename (varchar) 
•   surname (varchar) 
•   FK st_id (int)
```

The `storeTbl` This table references all of the stores in the group

```
•   PK st_id (int) 
•   store (varchar) 
•   storeNo (varchar) 
•   FK d_id (int)
```

The `shiftTbl` this table references the differing shift patterns

```
•   PK wa_id (int) 
•   Shift (varchar)
```

The `userAssessmentTbl` this table holds information relating to the user, the training which was undertaken and the outcome of that training.
The o_id can only be one value 1, 2, 3 or 4

```
•   PK ti_id (int) 
•   FK UserId (UID) 
•   FK tt_id (int) 
•   o_id (int) 
•   n_id (int)
```

The `setTbl` this table is the names of each of the training courses

```
•   PK s_id (int) 
•   setName (varchar) 
•   instruction (varchar) 
•   link (varchar) 
•   setNo (int)
```

This is my sql query string and if I do plain `LEFT JOIN`'s on the tables using the SQL below, I will get several rows related to one person:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * 
                       FROM userProfilesTbl 
                       LEFT JOIN storeTbl ON userProfilesTbl.st_id = storeTbl.st_id 
                       LEFT JOIN shiftTbl ON userProfilesTbl.wa_id = shiftTbl.wa_id
                       LEFT JOIN userAssessmentTbl ON userProfilesTbl.UserId = userAssessmentTbl.UserId 
                       LEFT JOIN trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id
                       LEFT JOIN setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id 
                       WHERE userProfilesTbl.st_id=@st_id 
                       AND userProfilesTbl.wa_id=@wa_id 
                       AND DATEPART(mm,t_date) = @m_date 
                       AND DATEPART(yyyy,t_date) = @y_date  
                       ORDER BY surname ASC"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge row values into a CSV (a.k.a GROUP\_CONCAT for SQL Server)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755815/merge-row-values-into-a-csv-a-k-a-group-concat-for-sql-server). This will allow you to concatenate the values per some value

Comment: Using SQL Server? This question looks like it has the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server

Comment: Hi gbn, can you expand further on your comment?