# Problems with the execution of a sp in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've been trying to execute the next sp. My target is to generate a string with the values of several ID. This is what I've done:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_IDENTIF @ID NVARCHAR OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN       
        DECLARE 
        @DATUM NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @CONCAT NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @IDENTIFIC NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @T DATETIME ;
        SET @IDENTIFIC = '';

        DECLARE IDENTIFIERS CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
            SELECT TOP 2 ID
            FROM TABLE_1
            WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
            UNION 
            SELECT TOP 2 ID
            FROM TABLE_2
            WHERE ID IS NOT NULL

        OPEN IDENTIFIERS
            FETCH NEXT FROM IDENTIFIERS INTO @DATUM
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    BEGIN  
                    PRINT @IDENTIFIC;
                    SELECT @IDENTIFIC = CONCAT(@IDENTIFIC,',OR ID =''',@DATUM,'''');
                    FETCH NEXT FROM IDENTIFIERS INTO @DATOS;    
                    END;

        CLOSE IDENTIFIERS;
        SET @ID =  @IDENTIFIC;  
        PRINT('THE IDENTIFIERS ARE: '+@ID);
        RETURN;
END
```

If I execute the union query I will have the next output (obviously the top keyword is just to test the result):

```
ID
101075330-IC001
ACP-2582785
ACP-645655
ACP-942612
```

But when I call the sp I am getting the next output:

```
declare @identific nvarchar(max);
exec sp_Identif @identific output;
print 'The ID set is: '+@identific;


,OR ID ='101075330-IC001'
,OR ID ='101075330-IC001',OR ID ='ACP-2582785'
,OR ID ='101075330-IC001',OR ID ='ACP-2582785',OR ID ='ACP-645655'
THE IDENTIFIERS ARE : ,
The ID set is :
```

I am printing the result of the variable @identif and @Id to check what is going on with its value. As you can see can see only 3 Id's inserted in the string variable durint the fetch loop, but at the end of the cycle I do not have any value recordint in the output variable.

What am I doing wrong with this code?, and is there another way to reach the same target?. I am trying to implement a SP that is going to be called from SSIS.

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing wrong?  Nvarchar without length, top without order by, cursors, sp_ prefix from a quick look.

Comment: Here are a few examples of that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193152/sql-server-convert-select-a-column-and-convert-it-to-a-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is that `@ID NVARCHAR` is equivalent to `@ID NVARCHAR(1)` and you are getting truncation.

You don't need a cursor here either and the `sp_` prefix should be avoided as it is reserved for Microsoft system procedures.

The following would return an output of

> ,OR ID ='101075330-IC001',OR ID ='ACP-2582785',OR ID ='ACP-645655',OR
>   ID ='ACP-942612'

from your example input

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_IDENTIF (@ID NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT)
AS
  BEGIN
      WITH T(ID)
           AS (SELECT ID
               FROM   TABLE_1
               WHERE  ID IS NOT NULL
               UNION
               SELECT ID
               FROM   TABLE_2
               WHERE  ID IS NOT NULL)
      SELECT @ID = CAST((SELECT CONCAT(',OR ID =''', ID, '''')
                         FROM   T
                         FOR XML PATH('')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
  END
```