# How to send column data as a comma separated string from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

**TWO PART QUESTION**

I'll try to explain this as best I can.

**PART 1**

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

the two last rows are identical exept for the types and UrlId.

I have a SP that I call that executes the following query to get me the data above:

```
SELECT Urlid, DomainName, OrgId, DomainId, s.TypeId AS TypeId
FROM DomainData d
JOIN SystemUrls s ON s.DomainId = d.Id
WHERE @OrgId IS NULL OR  OrgId = @OrgId
```

***How can I make so that the data looks like?***:

```
Name(varchar)   OrgId(bigint)        DomainId(bigint)  TypeId(int)
Three            556548-4499             71              2,1
```

**PART 2**

Assuming that I dont change the above result and decide to change it on the server with a linq-query(C#)

***How would a linq-query look like to give me the desiered result?***

Comment: have you tried anything? In mysql it is called group_concat -> and there are SO questions asking how to do it in sql server. For the linq - have you tried?

Comment: Look into XML Stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server

Comment: @Gilad Green I have tried a few groupby clauses. i haven not used group_concat and wasn't even aware of it untill i read your comment. my knowledge of lets call the above advance tsql is limited.Edit: i would not post a question simply looking for an answer without attempting to solve it on my own.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN - That is fine, and I'm happy to help with the stuff but effort from your side must be shown - that is why we ask to post code you've tried

Comment: My question is why do you want to pass delimited values in the first place? They are a pain to work with because you will have to split them apart again anyway.

Comment: @Sean Lange in this scenario i would not have to split it again, i will only show the data as is on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 1 - then look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server). Someone answered before me so I won't repeat :)

For part 2 - Split it into 2 parts - the first is to select the joint data and then after having it in memory (`ToList()`) you can use `string.Join` to concatenate all the `TypeId`s

```
var jointData = (from d in db.DomainData
                 join s in db.SystemUrls on d.Id equals s.DomainId into sg
                 new { m.DomainName, m.OrgId, DomainId = m.Id, s.TypeId }).ToList();

var result = jointData.GroupBy(item => new { item.DomainName, item.OrgId, item.DomainId })
             .Select(g => new { 
                 g.Key.DomainName, 
                 g.Key.OrgId, 
                 g.Key.DomainId, 
                 TypeId = string.Join(", ", g.Select(item => item.TypeId))
             });
```

Comment: What would happen if you tried to run that in one shot? I.e do the GroupBy/Select before the call to ToList. My only guess why you broke it up into 2 parts is because string.Join won't have a translation to SQL and it'd throw an exception

Comment: This worked like a charm. I am experimenting with XML STUFF for the tsql soloution but this is great. Thank you!

Comment: @applejacks01 - So I didn't test it in one go because I currently don't have a database to test it against but from what I know - ya it will fail on not knowing how to perform the string.join

Comment: @Ra3IDeN - you are welcome :) In my opinion if you have the stuff mapped and it is select operations then use linq

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you:
Note: I'm considering Urlid, DomainName, OrgId, DomainId belongs to "DomainData " and Id , TypeId belongs to "SystemUrls" table.

```
    SELECT  DomainName, OrgId, Id, 
    STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + cast(s2.TypeId as varchar(5))
                    FROM    SystemUrls AS s2 
                    WHERE   s2.DomainId = d.Id
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 2, '') as TypeId

    FROM DomainData d
    WHERE @OrgId IS NULL OR  OrgId = @OrgId 
    GROUP BY DomainName, OrgId, Id
```

Comment: I was pretty close with my first attempt. I was just to stuburn to remove the join that I had which gave me complications. Thank you this worked:)
Edited: changes part of it since small parts of your assumption where wrong.

Answer (score -2):

first create temp table,
and declaration with expected range when you want it all in long string format datatype and size may effect so make sure to that.

then,

```
  insert into #temp(
  Urlid, DomainName, OrgId, DomainId, s.TypeId)
  SELECT Urlid, DomainName, OrgId, DomainId, s.TypeId
  FROM DomainData d
  JOIN SystemUrls s ON s.DomainId = d.Id
  WHERE @OrgId IS NULL OR  OrgId = @OrgId 

 declare @Column1 varchar(350),
 select @Column1= coalesce(@Column1+',','')+convert(varchar(30),TypeId )
 from #temp

update #temp
set Typeid=@column1
from #temp

select * from #temp
```

by the way this question has been answered previously try not to create duplicate entry this is the link:[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193152/sql-server-convert-select-a-column-and-convert-it-to-a-string)

Comment: This sets all the typeIds to the same comma separated value. Which is wrong