# Concatenated distinct values with column names

Tags: sql-server

What is the most efficient way to get a concatenated list of distinct values from selected columns on SQL Server?

```
Col1    Col2    Col3 

A       3       C23

A       3       C32

B       2       D12

C       1       C23

D       5       D12

D       5       C32
```

My target output is a table as follows:

```
ColumnNames        DistinctValues

Col1              {A,B,C,D}

Col2              {1,2,3,5}

Col3              {C23,C32,D12}
```

Would be great if I could specify which columns to be looked up.

Comment: [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server) for a start.

Comment: which version? from 2017 you can use STRING_AGG()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server convert select a column and convert it to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193152/sql-server-convert-select-a-column-and-convert-it-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to unpivot the data

```
SELECT * 
FROM   yourtable 
       CROSS apply (VALUES(col1,'Col1'), 
                          (Cast(col2 AS VARCHAR(50)),'Col2'), 
                          (col3,'Col3')) tc(val, columnnames)
```

then concatenate based on the column names to get the result

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   yourtable 
                CROSS apply (VALUES(col1,'Col1'), 
                                   (Cast(col2 AS VARCHAR(50)),'Col2'), 
                                   (col3, 'Col3')) tc(val, columnnames)) 
SELECT DISTINCT columnnames, 
                '{'+Stuff(distinctvalues, 1, 1, '')+'}'
FROM   cte a 
       CROSS apply(SELECT DISTINCT ',' + val 
                   FROM   cte b 
                   WHERE  a.columnnames = b.columnnames 
                   FOR xml path('')) cs (distinctvalues)
```

- [**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2d4119/2)

Another approach

```
SELECT 'Col1', 
       Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + col1 
              FROM   yourtable 
              FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Col2', 
       Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Cast(col2 AS VARCHAR(50)) 
              FROM   yourtable 
              FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Col3', 
       Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + col3 
              FROM   yourtable 
              FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: Sorry brand new to sql and to stackoverflow questioning, done!

Comment: Ah ... sorry but for large tables this is way slower than running individual distinct queries :(

Comment: @Kam- This is the best the possible approach I can think of.. Group Concatenation isn't the strongest part of sql server. Another issue is we are unpivoting the data before concatenating to get the result in desired format ..

Comment: @P????  thank you for your help. I think that is the way to go -- get the results and then format the output. BTW, is there a way to wrap it in a loop (with some tests to identify the data type) instead of writing repetitive statements?